# Changing the value of onclick in jquery

Tags: jquery, onclick

There are many topics on this and I have tried the solutions, but nothing is working. I am not a javascript developer, so might be not able to figure out.

I have a onclick function in my html (php template file)

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="AddFav({$id});" title="Add to Favs">Fav</a>
```

On click, jquery ajax function is being called and on success, I want to change the value of onclick to RemoveFav({$id}. I am changine the value of title with .attr.

```
$('div#fav-'+ id +' a').unbind('click').removeAttr('onclick').click(RemoveFav(id););
```

Please do help me with the same.

Comment: why not have one function on the onClick event, but a global variable (0 or 1) and when it's 0 - add to fav, when it's 1 remove from fav ?

I'd say this is a nice solution since if they visit the site again, but already favved, they also want to see 'remove fav', so you can set the global variable according to a value in the database.

Comment: Hi @PoeHaH, even I thought of that solution. When the page is loaded, it checks for each item whether it is faved or not. Accordingly the onclick function changes to AddFav or RemoveFav. We can have that in same function, but then again how do we change the value of 0 to 1 and vice versa on every click.

Comment: I'll post it in an answer, because code looks better there :)

Comment: @Vineshkumar Kunhiraman - you can add a class to the Fav elements something like: if($(this).filter('[data-fav]').length>0){ $(this).removeAttr('data-fav') } else { $(this).attr('data-fav',true); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.click` need a callback function.

```
$('div#fav-'+ id +' a').unbind('click').removeAttr('onclick').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  RemoveFav(id);
});
```

Comment: Hi @xdazz, thanks for the quick reply. I tried your solution. But now the click function has stopped working. :(

Comment: @VineshkumarKunhiraman Try set `href="#"` and use my edited code.

Comment: Hi @xdazz, it worked. There was a mistake from my end, I didnt close the brackets {} properly. Thanks friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you do my suggestion in the comments your code should look something like this:

```
var removeFav = 0; // this should be set according to database query, to check if it's favved

function toggleFav()
{
    if(removeFav == 0)
    {
     //code to add fav
     removefav = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      //code to remove fav
     removefav = 0;
    }

}
```